# Wiring a switch to a series of outlets

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

I am looking to wire 5 outlets on a custom table. I'd like there to be a switch at the beginning of the run to shut power on/off to all switches at once. What is the best way to accomplish this, and is there a wirigin diagram I can use for this? My thought was to use a 3 prong appliance cord to provide power to the table (at the switch) and it would be plugged into a wall outlet. The switch would prevent me from having to plug/unplug the table each time.

I assume the black wire from the source would go to the switch and the black wire from the first outlet would also go to the switch. Then the neutral from the source would get capped with the neutral from the first outlet. Then from there it would be co

Comment: ...Then from there it would be connecting each outlets black and white wire to the outlet before it?

Comment: please do not use a comment to update your question ... click the `edit` button and make changes to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have it correct. You would wire this up almost like a chain of receptacles in the wall. The key things are:

- You use a *cord* from the switch box to the wall. This is officially called "cordage". You can get it at any length from an electrical supply house and connect it to the switch box on one and and to a plug on the other end. Or you can get a preassembled cord/plug from a big box store or hardware store. The one thing you need to watch is the size (AWG) of the wires. If you are powering lots of little things then 14 AWG for 15A max. is fine. But if you are plugging this into a 20A receptacle and some of your loads are large then 12 AWG for 20A max. is better.
- Between the switches you can either use non-metallic cable (NM), a.k.a., Romex, or you can use individual wires in conduit. In this particular case, I suggest Legrand Wiremold. This is commonly used when wires can't be run inside walls for some reason, and I think it looks quite good installed as part of a table. Again, 12 AWG allows 20A, 14 AWG for 15A.
- You do *not* need GFCI protection in the table itself. Depending on the location (and local code adoption and age of the installed wiring) you may or may not need GFCI protection on the circuit. But since this is a plug-in device it is not affected by those rules. However, if the circuit you will be plugging this into does *not* have GFCI protection and you will be working with any liquids on the table then GFCI (somewhere) is a good idea.
- Depending on how you plan to use the table, you can have receptacles on vertical parts above the main surface, on vertical parts below the main surface, or even on the main surface itself! Consider pop-up receptacles or other unusual configurations.
- While some people don't like combination USB/receptacles, if you have a use for USB power that can be a great addition here to avoid a proliferation of USB power adapters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did confirm it's a 15A circuit and the breaker is GFCI already, so that's a plus. Primarily it'll be used for a TV, Laptop and a couple phone chargers via USB. The cord I got was a 14AWG/15A max, and eventhough it's overkill, I got 12/2 romex for the wiring incase we ever decide to upgrade anything down the road. Again I really appreciate the quick and detailed answer!

Comment: But is it code-compliant to cut off the female end of the extension cord and connect it to a switch (which is what I assume is what the OP wants to do)?

Comment: @Huesmann Not *technically* code but rather violating the UL/ETL listing of the cord. Though arguably "OK" in any practical sense. But in fact a "3 prong appliance cord" is *not* an extension cord with an end chopped off. It is a cord/plug with the other end being wires designed to be installed to replace an existing appliance cord. Routinely done with dryers (because 3 vs. 4 wire so none of them come with a cord) but readily available as replacements for 120V appliances as well. Which is then 100% normal use and not a problem at all.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact if that's the case, the OP will need to provide some kind of clamp on the cord to secure it, other than the connections inside the first box.

Comment: @Huesmann I thought about that. But didn't bother to say anything since clamps are *also* needed for the Romex.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact but *are* clamps needed for Romex?  The guy is gonna have to run some kind of protection (I'm assuming all the wiring will run *under* the table)—whether conduit, wiremold, smurf tube—which don't ordinarily require cable to be *clamped* to anything, just appropriate bushings at boxes, no?

Comment: @Huesmann I'm referring to the clamps on the boxes. Now I see what you're saying - yes, the cord should have an additional clamp before the first box to hold it to the table so it won't get yanked from the box. Minor issue - easy enough to take care of. As far as the Romex - depending on design of the table, it may be quite well protected. Remember the reason *in or on walls* for protection is (a) against external damage (depending on routing of the cable that may not be an issue on the table) and (b) against damage from making holes in the wall - not an issue here. So really shouldn't be hard

Comment: to design in a way that exposed Romex is OK here. That being said, I personally like the wiremold idea but it all depends on the desired style.